# How does check in process works in Sharepoint?

Tags: css, check-in, font-awesome

[image: Fonts_b4checkin]my question is very general. Since past Monday, every page on my site if I "edit" the page (regardless of if it is front page or subsite page), the top navigation fonts would change after I press "check in".

I can "edit" a page and dont make any modification but simply press edit page then check in and publish and the font would change.

Is this caused by CSS?

How does the process works? So after I check in the page, a java script or what runs in the background?

Thanks and sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

[image: Fonts_aftercheckin]

Comment: do you have a screen shot of what the fonts look like as they change?

Comment: Screen shots posted.

Comment: Not only the font type changed, the font size also changed and after check in, the drop down menu stop working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question should not be about "how the check-in process works in the background" rather, "why my page renderes differently when it is checked-out".

What SharePoint version do you have? Online? On-premise (did some update installed recently on the SharePoint farm)? Is your font loaded on page that is checked-out (Developer tools (F12) > Network)? Try to check if some Javascript error occures on the checked-out page (Developer tools (F12) > Console)

Apparently when the page is checked-out some other CSS elements are loaded  to the page that influence the rendered page. You have to use Developer tools (F12) in the browser to identify which CSS styles are applied to your navigation.

[image: Developer tools in Google Chrome]
*How to identify which CSS styles are aplied to HTML element in Google Chrome.*

Comment: Thanks Luckas for your comment. I did use F12 but just didn't know what to look for.  We do use Online version of the Sharepoint. Everything was working fine until last week and no one has changed CSS in our org.So would CSS just changed by itself? Thanks